# Charecter encoding in PHP not working for double quotes

Tags: php

I have a PHP script which reads some input and saved it in the database. The input could have single or double quotes. I am changing the quotes to their ISO Latin-1 codes to avoid problems with escaping. For single quotes, my code is:

```
$str = str_replace("'", "&#039;", $str);
```

With this code, if the input is "Jack's book", it is being correctly saved in the database as Jack's (code in place of ') book. But when I do this with double quotes:

```
$str = str_replace("\"", "&#034;", $str);
```

nothing gets saved in the database at all. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Which content in this string?

Comment: It's working check again

Comment: this has nothing to do with the `str_replace()` function. you most likely got some error when saving the string to your database.

Comment: what do you mean by "avoid problems with escaping"? SQL Injection? Then you should use a better form of saving data to your database like php pdo class or a standard escaping function of php

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$str = str_replace('"', "&#034;", $str);
```

to do the job? (double-quote in single-quotes)